# Reallocate free space to Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I've just installed Ubuntu and get rid of the old Windows data but that leaves me with a big free partition.

Is there a way to merge the left free space into the right Ubuntu space ?

I can't resize the right one into the left one and I don't really get why…
Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's blocked because you are using it. 
Load from live USB or your installation disk, Try Ubuntu, open GParted and then you'll be able to add the unallocated memory to your Ubuntu partition.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you :D